# Want to remove third party Custom Controls from ToolBox in VS2010 which were created while installing the msiinstaller through .pkgdef files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, toolbox

I have software where I am giving the third party controls through `.pkgdef` file and give access to user to use those controls when he installs the software.

But when I uninstall the software the Controls are still present in VS2010. I would like to know if there is any solution where i can remove them when I uninstall the software.
My pkgdef file looks like this

```
Example: [$RootKey$\ToolboxControlsInstaller\TekButtons, Version=6.1.90.105, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
@="Tek Components"
"Codebase"="C:\Program Files\Tek\SYSTEM\TekButtons.dll"
```

So when the user installs the msi installer, he will be able to see some custom controls on ToolBox.

Now the Quest is how to remove them when I uninstall the Software.

Please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial article I wrote recently on the topic:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

If your component is in a form of VSIX package, then "VsixInstaller.exe /uninstall:GUID /quiet" (put GUID of your component in the place of the word 'GUID').

If your component is installed using MSI which is usually combined with TCI (Toolbox Controls Installer), then simply removing a registry entry would do. For example:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller\SampleControl, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3cc4c7b61201d46c
```